# ReactJS: Image display not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image-upload

So I have this scenario where I am uploading the images. On front end, its `React Js` and back end in `Node Js`. Images get uploaded fine but when I have to display them on front end it doesn't work.

I am using [react-image-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery) to display images like this:

```
<ImageGallery
   items={this.state.currentImages}
   lazyLoad={true}
   ref={this.myRef}
   showIndex={true}
/>
```

This is what is there in `this.state.currentImages`:

```
[
    {
        "original": "/var/www/html/ciaoOrderTaking/projects/ciao_full_stack/uploads/images/items/IMAGE-1645782694696.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "/var/www/html/ciaoOrderTaking/projects/ciao_full_stack/uploads/images/items/IMAGE-1645782694696.jpg"
    }
]
```

In the browser the path becomes:

> http://localhost:3000/var/www/html/ciaoOrderTaking/projects/ciao_full_stack/uploads/images/items/IMAGE-1645782694696.jpg

How can I make it work? Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External link in react is being appended with localhost if no http or https present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720487/external-link-in-react-is-being-appended-with-localhost-if-no-http-or-https-pres)

Comment: @SohaibAlqasem no it doesn't. I tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was the answer.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to make URL and serve your uploaded files statically in the backend e.g., your backend port is 3000 and you have served statically uploads folder on nodejs backend.
Upload folder structure:
Uploads -> Images -> items -> IMAGE-1645782694696.jpg
Now your file URL will become:
http://localhost:3000/images/items/IMAGE-1645782694696.jpg

So make an function in the frontend which will convert your image url into accessible File URL like:

```
const toAbsoluteURL=(url)=>{
  return `http://localhost:3000/${url}` // note that this is backend url
}
```

And map the function to array of images.

```
images=images.map((url)=>toAbsoluteURL(url?.original)); // now images array have accessible file urls
```

**You can make accessible URL's with the above function as you want.**

Comment: I tried this way but didn't work.

Comment: Can you please attach codesandbox